# The div for lefthand navigation will not expand with the content. Height:auto not working

Tags: html, css, height

I have a lefthand navigation gradient background that needs to expand vertically based on the amount of content in the body of the page. The navigation div (#left-nav) is set to auto height but it will only expand to the size of the list within it. If I set a fixed height, the background gradient responds but I can't figure out why height:auto does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code using just a black background to avoid extraneous code for the gradient:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left-nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a class="class3" href="#">nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="class3" href="#">nav 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="class3" href="#">nav 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="class3" href="#">nav 4</a></li>                                       
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="body-main">
    <p>content</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {float:left; width:1000px;}
#left-nav {background:#000000; float:left; height:auto; width:180px;}
#left-nav li a {display: block; font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom:20px;}
.nav-list {padding-top:25px; width:180px;}
a.class3 {color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.content {positon:relative;float:left; width:1000px;}
#body-main {margin-left:200px;}
#left-nav {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:180px;background:#000000;}
```

Comment: Interesting. That worked. Ever had any browser issues or breaks in responsive layouts with the positioning? Thanks Doug!

Comment: You can always adjust the positioning in a media query and make the div not be absolute if you need to. It's all in what you're trying to get out of the page.